# Detach/Attach WPF Datagrid from One Window to Another Causes Items to Not Be Rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I detach my bounded (by ItemsSource property) datagrid from one window and then attach it to another window, the items in the datagrid are not rendered.

```
window1.Content = null; //before this, my datagrid is displayed without problems
window2.Content = myDataGrid; //now I only see the column headers
```

I've tried calling UpdateLayout on both the Window and the datagrid, I've tried Measure/Arrange. I'm not sure what the problem is. Any idea on why this is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to refresh your datagrid by calling:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myDataGrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

or

```
myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

or

```
System.Collections.IEnumerable temp = myDataGrid.ItemsSource;
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = temp;
```

hope this helps, regards